# Reporting capital gains as an F-1 student in the US

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, f1-student-visa

United States

Since I was on an F-1 STEM OPT status in 2021, my brokerage company issued me a 1042-S form. This only shows the dividends and interest, but not the capital gains.

How do I calculate my capital gains and report it?

Comment: Did you have capital gains? Where they from you selling shares or from the funds distributing their gains?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep They were from both - selling shares and dividends (and cash from mergers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capital-gain distributions from a mutual fund (or more generally a regulated investment company) to a US-defined 'nonresident alien' *should* be reported on 1042-S with code 36, but not withheld on, according to the instructions and pub 515. Check with the broker about this; since 1042-S (and the underlying 1042) is *mostly* about withholding, their system may have confused no-withholding with no-reporting. I'm pretty sure they are taxable to you in the same fashion as 'direct' gains below (and without the short-term/long-term distinction for 'resident' taxpayers), but haven't found a clear authority for this; if I do I will add it.

For 'direct' gains and losses = when you sell or otherwise obtain value for an asset, there is no withholding except (on NRA) for real property and possibly certain partnership interests (the latter was recently added and I don't think it's implemented yet), neither of which applies here. AFAICS the broker is not required to file and furnish (to you) 1099-B, as they are for a 'resident' taxpayer. Given you were in US at least 183 days of the year and were not investing as part of a business (i.e. not 'effectively connected'), you are required to report these on 1040NR schedule NEC, see [pub 519 under "Sales or Exchanges of Capital Assets"](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2021_publink1000222353), and pay tax at applicable treaty rate or 30%.

You should be able to determine your proceeds and basis from transaction records (confirmations) or statements. Alternatively, for *resident* holders of 'noncovered' securities (basically, those bought before about 2012, but the details can be complicated) where the broker is not required to report basis and holding information on 1099-B, they almost always (IME) maintain this information anyway and provide it *with* the 1099-B but labelled as 'supplementary information' or similar; you might ask the broker if they offer/provide such info, or look on their website for something resembling this.

Shares involved a cash-only acquisition/merger are the same as a (simple) sale, but if you have any cash-plus-new-stock case that gets more complicated, and doing it yourself (without 1099-B) may be difficult. I won't go into this unless necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer! To clarify, in your first line, does "mutual fund (or more generally a regulated investment company)" also refer to stocks and cryptocurrency (apologies if this is an elementary question)?

Secondly, if my brokerage does not give me a summary of capital gains owed and I am unsure of how to calculate it, would an accountant be the right person to seek the help of?

Comment: rahs: no. 'regulated investment company' (RIC) is (in practice) a mutual fund (or ETF, but ETF's generally don't have realized cap gains to distribute), real estate investment trust, or unit investment trust. Note (plain) stocks and cryptos never _distribute_ cap gains to you as a holder. However, people are trying to create funds/ETFs for crypto, and if they do and you invest with _them_ you're back to my first case. ...

Comment: ... If you can graduate college IMO you should be able to do this; it is not, as we say, rocket science; but if you need help an accountant certainly should be able; OTOH people specifically in the business of preparing taxes like Intuit/Turbotax and HRBlock _may_ be sufficient and very likely cheaper. For myself if I weren't committed to doing my own, I would try tax-prep first and 'move up' only if needed.

Comment: Thanks again. Aren't gains from selling stocks considered capital gains?

Comment: Absolutely (assuming you are an investor, not working as a broker/dealer) and I didn't say otherwise. If _you_ sell (or otherwise dispose for value) stock, _or_ shares in a fund, _or_ other property like cryptocurrency, you have a cap gain or loss. If a fund disposes of stock (or possibly crypto), the _fund_ has a cap gain or loss, but (in US) the fund is required to _distribute_ (pay out) net cap gains to holders like you; that is a cap gain _distribution_ (usually happens in Dec). A stock you hold directly can give you a cap gain when you sell, but not a cap gain _distribution_.

Comment: I see. So if I were to sell my stocks through an app such as Robinhood, the gains from those transactions would contribute to my capital gains (which in your answer are also referred to as 'direct gains') and those gains from a mutual fund are distributions. Got it.